# Как установить PyQt 5.7.1?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как установить PyQt 5.7.1?

**Именно 5.7.1**, последняя версия **не нужна**.

---

PS: ОС Windows 7 x64

Comment: `pip install PyQt5==5.7.1`

Comment: я в шоке((( 2 дня, 2 дня

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, пожалуйста, оформите, в виде ответа свой комментарий

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pip позволяет указывать версию

```
pip install PyQt5==5.7.1
```